# How to track activity time on a page, and send the data to the backend without sending too many requests?

Tags: javascript

I need to create an analytics script that would give an idea of how long each user spent on each page. I can't use 3rd party software like Google Analytics so I have to write it my own.

I am not sure as to what would be the best way to actually track and send the data in the least "demanding" way on the server. I am not using WebSockets.

Right now I have 3 ideas on how to track and send the activity to the backend:

1. Use `mousemove` and `keydown` events on the page, and when the movement stops, wait a few seconds and then if it really stopped send AJAX with the needed details
2. Use `mousemove` and `keydown` events on the page, but save the activity time in a cookie or SessionStorage, and send AJAX every few seconds (polling) with the most updated data.
3. (This is a new update to this post) - This is a combination between method 1 and method 2 - What I will do is, I will use polling every X seconds, but only as long as there is an activity on the page. When activity stops - clear the polling (Is it even possible? I was thinking to use `setInterval` with `setTimeout` somehow)

***Edit:** This is not a video-watching website where lack of movement might still mean that the user is active and viewing a video - so basically if there is no movement in the website, the user is not doing anything.

But is this enough to actually track activity, and, are these methods of sending data alright, or  I will need to use another approach? I was just thinking that these options may take too many resources, for example too many requests to the server. So maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Be aware that visually impaired users might only use a keyboard instead of the mouse. You should also take touch events into consideration to fully support mobile users

Comment: Oh good point, thank you. Then I will add `keydown` (updated the post). That should be enough for the tracking part?

Comment: Be aware of multi tabs could cause multi requests too.

Comment: @HuyDuy Exactly that's what I'm afraid of. But if I use the first method - I know that only the active tab will send the requests. Using the second method it will send many requests. So I am not sure what's better - the first one where many requests might be sent from a single tab, or the second method - where many requests will be sent if multiple tabs/windows are opened

Comment: You could also use a [Shared Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) to keep track of all pages

Comment: I never used it, but I am going to take a look now - but if I get it by the name, it means I can track activity on my domain on all open windows/tabs, and create a listener that will have the information of the currently active window/tab? So if I move mouse from 1 window to another I can actually track that "jump" with all information needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think option 1 is good.  Like @Reyno said, make sure to track all relevant events.  To avoid multiple requests and only make a request when the user truly stops, you can do something like this:

```
let timeout

document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('user stopped moving')
        // Perform AJAX request here
    }, 5000)
})
```

When the timeout is cleared, you never end up performing the request.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized something that might be bad if using `setTimeout` - if a user works long time but immediately quits the page - there will never be any update. Maybe I should somehow use `setInterval` instead - and do a mix between the first and second methods - i.e. to poll as long as there is activity, but stop polling when activity stops?

Comment: No problem.  Didn't know what we were tracking.  Just understood we needed some detection of when a user stopped typing or moving the mouse.  Based on what you wrote now, I think it might be a good idea.  I made something like that a few months ago.  I was polling a service every minute to see if certain information was being imported.  If the service was being imported, the interval between each poll switched to 10 seconds, so the client could more closely catch when the importing stopped.  Of course your case isn't the same, but I think the idea of a dynamic interval might be good here too.